# Rules for single-word comparatives and superlatives

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“More clear” vs “Clearer”, when to use “more” instead of “-er”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

Are there any rules for which words are allowed to have `-er` and `-est` endings? Being a native speaker, I do it by ear, but what distinguishes **free/freer/freest**, **calm/calmer/calmest**, and **speedy/speedier/speediest** from **watchful/*watchfuller/*watchfullest** or **creative/*creativer/*creativest** ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIRC, one-syllable adjectives or two-syllable adjectives words ending on "y" have comparatives with -"er", all other adjectives use "more/most". Let's see if I can find a source for that though....

---

Hmmm does English SE count as a source? :)

["More clear" vs "Clearer": when to use "more" instead of "-er"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/)