# What's the comparative for the word "modern"?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“More clear” vs “Clearer”, when to use “more” instead of “-er”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

What's the comparative for the word *modern*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> More modern.

"Moderner" is entirely non-standard.  If you want to avoid "more", you could use a synonym like "fresher" instead.  Of course, it's not a full synonym, but it may serve your purpose.