# "Simpler" or "More Simple"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“More clear” vs “Clearer”, when to use “more” instead of “-er”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

Which of these two terms is correct?  If they are both correct, are they identical in usage and meaning, or is one of the words more appropriate for some usages than the other?

Answer (score 18):

It is simpler to use *simpler* when you want to express that one thing is simpler than something else.

*Simpler* is a word that is in use for this very purpose, so don't waste your breath, ink or electricity with *more simple*.