# Julie's guests arrived slightly earlier/ more early

Tags: comparatives, adverbials

The task is 'Complete the sentences by changing the words in brackets into comparative adverbs'.

The sentence is 'Julie's guests arrived slightly ... (early) than she expected'.

Finally, the answer is 'earlier'. **However,**

1. The [BC Learn English Web site says](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/comparative-and-superlative-adverbs)**Two or more syllables: Alan finished the test quickly. >   more quickly    >   most quickly.** The table is attached at the end.
2. 'Early' consists of 2 syllables according to multiple sources including [this one](https://www.howmanysyllables.com/syllables/early#:%7E:text=Wondering%20why%20early%20is%202,Contact%20Us!)

Regarding these two pieces of information, the right answer should be 'more early'.

I read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78244/speak-slower-or-speak-slowlier) thread before writing this question but it doesn't provide an answer to my question because the approved answer accepts 'speak slower' as correct -which may perfectly be, I don't have enough knowledge to judge- however; 'speak slower' is incorrect English according to the rules and guidelines listed on BC Learn English Web site -which I cited on the top- as 'slower' consists of 2 syllables.

My question is why does 'more early' is not the answer?

[image]

Comment: It's incorrect to fix 2 syllables as needing 'more' since it's variable for 2 syllables: English uses 'earlier'. Second row "ending in e," doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: I've never heard of that rule. _Early_ is certainly an exception to it.

Comment: You need a better source. Try https://www.onestopenglish.com/support-for-teaching-grammar/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives-article/144846.article — and note the words *generally*, *usually*, *sometimes*, and *exceptions*.

Comment: Happier, sillier, etc. Stupider is common.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant: remove the adverbial ending from "quickly" and you have the adjective. (quickly/quick) But removing the adverbial ending from "early" does not yield a valid adjective.  Euphony is an opinion, but "earlier" is much easier to hear than "quicklier."

Answer (score 2):

The actual rule is:

> If there is only one syllable, add "er" (there are exceptions to this — *more fun*).

> If there are two syllables, it depends on the word: *early →  earlier*, *silly → sillier*, *simple → simpler*, but *stupid → more stupid*, *orange →  more orange*, *likely → more likely*. For some adjectives, both forms are acceptable.

> If there are three or more syllables, use *more*. I don't know of any exceptions to this.

Comment: Some types of 3-syllable words derived from productive prefixes can still take normal inflections. For example, there’s a lot of publication history for using words like *unhappier* and *unhappiest* and even *uncommonest*, perhaps because those start out life as *happy* and *common*. On the other hand, sometimes even short words derived from Latinate sources instead of Germanic ones resist those, like the way we are more apt to say *more just* than *juster*, or for that matter to say *more apt* than *apter*, especially in this century.

Comment: @tchrist: *more uncommon* and *more unhappy* are commoner than *uncommoner* and *unhappier*, so I don't think you can go wrong with the rule *with three or more syllables, use more*. (Although *less common* and *less happy* are even more common.)

Comment: Phonologically, bisyllables ending in /i/ or /o/ frequently take _-er_, e.g, _earlier, narrower, livelier, easier, nastier, hollower_, ...

Answer (score 0):

A complete  description of the formation  of comparatives for  adverbs is given  in **CoGEl**  (*A comprehensive grammar of the English laguage*). (It is complete as far as it treats  the main points) The rule for adverbs is  derived from  that for adjectives.

*Adjectives*

> (**CoGEL § 7.81**) **Choice between inflectional and periphrastic comparison**
>
> The choice between inflectional and periphrastic comparison is largely
> determined by the length of the adjective.
> (a) Monosyllabic adjectives normally form their comparison by inflection:
> *low* - *lower* - *lowest*
> *Real, right, wrong*, and the preposition *like*  take only periphrastic forms:
>
> - She is  more like her grandmother.
>   <s>She is   liker her grandmother.</s>
>
> However, most other monosyllabic adjectives can take either inflectional or periphrastic comparison.
> (b) Many disyllabic adjectives can also take inflections, though they have the alternative of the periphrastic forms:
>
> - Her childre are *politer/more polite.*
> - Her childre are *(the) politest/(the) most polite.*
>
> Disyllabic adjectives that can most readily take inflected forms are those ending in an unstressed vowel, [syllabic l, as in "able"] or [schwa (r coloured schwa  in AmE)], eg:
> -- **y**: early, easy, funny, happy, noisy, wealthy, pretty
> -- **ow**: mellow, narrow, shallow
> -- **le**: able, feeble, gentle, noble, simple
> -- **er, ure**: clever, mature, obscure  [user LPH's addition: not"eager","proper",etc.]

*Aderbs*

> (**CoGEL § 7.83**) **Comparison of adverbs**
>
> (e) Adverbs that are identical in form with adjectives take
> inflections: *fast, hard, late, long, quick*. They follow the same spelling and phonological rules as for adjectives, eg:
> *early - earlier - earliest*
>
> - You have to work *harder/faster/longer*.
>   Then-er - -est inflections cannot be added to open-class adverbs ending in *-ly* :
> - *quickly -- more quickly <s>quicklier</s>*
>                  *-- more quickly <s>quickliest</s>*
>
> When *earlier* is synonymous with *before (that)* or  *previously*, and when *later* is synonymous with *after (that)*, they are not comparatives of the adverbs *early* and *late*.

Note  that "most
readily" in "**7.81 b)**" implies no unique choice and nothing  as  to  the preference between the two use, which each user of English  has to determine through experience; the following ngrams show that.

[image]

[image]

"More early" is not exactly a form that you could call wrong, but it is hardly used in comparison  to "earlier".

[image]

Although  the pages of examples  for  "[more early](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20early%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" contain numerous occurrences, a patient examination will show that a great  many  of  those are false positives (for  instance, "more" does not modify the adjective but instead the noun it qualifies). Nevertheless, the periphrastic  form is found often enough (even  fairly recently) and it is sometimes used  to some advantage, so  that it  seems possible to say that it is not really incorrect.

([ref., 1972](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/An_history_of_early_opinions_concerning/o3LZAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22more+early%22&dq=%22more+early%22&printsec=frontcover))... And if this was the case then , we may safely conclude , that the Unitarians were much more numerous in a more early period , as it is well known that they kept losing , and not gaining ground , for several centuries

([ref., 2003](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Early_Responses_to_Hume_s_Life_and_Reput/oOrWAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22more+early%22&dq=%22more+early%22&printsec=frontcover)) This evening Mr Hume not quite so well , and goes to bed at a more early hour than he used to do . Ferry bridge , Sunday , 28th

([ref., 1974](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Essays_on_the_Early_Republic_1789_1815/TAQaAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22more+early%22&dq=%22more+early%22&printsec=frontcover)) .. the latter more early useful ... than they should otherwise be

([ref., 1973](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Theories_of_Education_in_Early_America_1/AGkB1SAs-YsC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22more+early%22&dq=%22more+early%22&printsec=frontcover))  I would therefore recommend to every parent to begin the establishment of authority much more early than is commonly supposed to be possible

(ref., 2000) Open bite could even be correlated with yet inadequate growth of the jaws to accommodate the disproportionately large size of the more early - maturing tongue that must posture forward for accommodation within the oral cavity

([ref., 1807](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Gardener_s_and_Botanist_s_Dictionary/reFBAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22more+early%22&pg=PP694&printsec=frontcover)) Sometimes it happens , by badness of weather , & c . that a considerable quantity is fown the first week in december , but the more early fowings generally produce the strongest crops

([ref., 1858](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Retrospect_of_Practical_Medicine_and/hRxGAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22more+early%22&pg=PA197&printsec=frontcover)) The improvement is most strongly marked in the acute cases , and the more early the operation the more successful is the result obtained

([ref., 1858](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Gardeners_Chronicle/CukozoHgAJUC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22more+early%22&pg=PA420&printsec=frontcover)) but there  are causes which  operate  in promoting its more early maturity

([ref.,1958](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/S%C5%8Ful_Taehakkyo_nonmunjip/ielMAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22more+early%22&dq=%22more+early%22&printsec=frontcover)) Pyrus serotina pear require more amount of nitrogen through the growing year , more moisturous and fertile soil , to start more early and rapid growth than apple eventhough the Korean weather condition in spring season is always

*In  this preceding case  the  use of the periphrastic form is quite understandable as "more" applies also to "rapid".*

([ref., 1814](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Thoughts_on_the_Origin_and_Descent_of_th/aSgwAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22more+early%22&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover)) The sweetness of climate ad fertility of soil in Asia Minor, were favourable to a early icrease of population, and consequently to the more early organization of civil society.

*This new occurrence  seems  justified by the need to make it clear that what  is meant is not  "preceding organization".*