# "More" used in front of "happy"

Tags: grammaticality

Is it ever wrong to use the word "more" in front of an adjective? For example, is the following sentence grammatically incorrect: "I am more happy when I am reading poetry"?

Comment: There's nothing at all "wrong" with ***more happy***. But you'd probably do better asking any future questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where answers are more likely to be tailored to the needs of non-native speakers.

Comment: Note - the general case has been covered by [“More clear” vs “Clearer”: when to use “more” instead of “-er”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/), so arguably this is a duplicate.

Comment: "Is it ever wrong"? No, not always. You will find occasions where *more happy* suits and *happier* doesn't; same applies to other adjectives as well. If I remember right, the question of "more versus *-er*" has already been dealt with here (or maybe on [ell.se] ) earlier.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er

Answer (score 4):

It would be more common to use a comparative, like **happier**, or something like *very happy*.

Comment: "Happiest" may also be appropriate, depending on context:  "I sometimes read novels or nonfiction works, but I am happiest when I am reading poetry."

Comment: I didn't use that because the original poster used "more happy" rather than "*most* happy".

Comment: 'She couldn't have been more happy' sounds 'more substantial' than 'She couldn't have been happier'; there may be style advantages on occasion. Oh, and 'more happy' is still a comparative: a _periphrastic comparative_.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether a comparative or superlative form exists.  As Oldcat rightly points out, those are preferred.

The happy, happier, happiest continuum doesn't hold up when applied to something like affluent.

Affluenter may be a word that I need to start using...

Comment: Affluenter LaGuardia Airport last night at 10 pm....

Comment: @Oldcat: **Affluenter age** on discovering that you got there first! (It probably works better with a Scottish or Northern accent though! :)