# What’s the opposite of “wider”?

Tags: antonyms, is-it-a-word, comparatives, inflectional-morphology

What is the opposite of *wide* and *wider*?

For instance, is the corresponding opposite to sentence one below really sentence two?

1. The Ipad2 is **wider** than the iPad Air.
2. The iPad Air is **narrower** than the iPad2.

I ask because *narrower* does not sound right to me.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with *narrower*.

Comment: Agree with Rupe. Slimmer or thinner may work either.

Comment: Generally, a three dimensional object has a length, width and height (or thickness).  They therefore can be (long/short), (wide/narrow) (tall/short or thin/thick).  Don't substitute thin for narrow they refer to different dimensions.

Comment: what about slim?http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slim?showCookiePolicy=true

Answer (score 3):

The antonyms of *wide* and *wider* are *narrow* and *narrower*. With most comparatives, you can opt to use the *-er* suffix or you can prepend the word *more*. Generally, multisyllable words, such as *narrow*, would be prepended with the word *more*. So, if you don't feel comfortable with the word *narrower* then you can use *more narrow*.

["More clear" vs "Clearer": when to use "more" instead of "-er"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

Comment: The rule is that one-syllable words take _-er_, three or more take _more_, and two-syllable words ending in tense vowels (_busy, narrow_) take _-er_; other bisyllables take _more_. The reason for the exception is that tense vowels have offglides that merge easily with the shwa of the suffix /'iziyər/ and /'nɛrowər/. They're the most common final vowels with offglides.  There aren't that many bisyllabic adjectives that end in tense vowels.

Comment: To adapt a comment by Reg Dwight, _If a question is adequately answered by a quick look in a readily available reference, it should not be answered in the first place, as it is off-topic as general reference._

Comment: My concern is not with using -er or "more". I think narrow refers to the inner dimension, whereas wide refers to both inner and outer dimensions. The opposite of wide, when referring to inner dimension is narrow. How about when referring to the outer dimension? The opposite of "wide alley" is "narrow alley". Can we say the opposite of "wide screen" is "narrow screen"?

Comment: @Per Yes I think we can. I don't think your "inner dimension" idea works. "Narrow boat", "narrow brush" and "narrow waist" are the first counter-examples that spring to my mind.

Comment: Having said that, it's true that if you said "narrow screen" I'd probably interpret it as being exceptionally narrow, even portrait rather than landscape format (otherwise why would you say it?). But if you said that one screen is narrower than another I'd take it to just mean "less wide".

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of *wide* is *narrow*, and your example is correct. If you're talking about the *depth* of the device, you could say it is *thinner* or *skinnier*. You could also say it's *less wide* if you don't like using narrower.

Answer (score 0):

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wide+or+*%2C+*+or+wide&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwide%20or%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20too%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20less%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20deep%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20wider%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20even%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20so%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20regional%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blong%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeep%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhigh%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bclose%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bedifices%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blarge%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfar%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bshort%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0) fairly conclusively picks out *narrow* as the opposite of *wide*. If you ask it for "* or wide" and "wide or *", where the asterisk is a wildcard, *narrow* leads by a wide margin. Conversely, [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=narrow+or+*%2C+*+or+narrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cnarrow%20or%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20broad%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20too%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20selfish%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20contracted%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20exclusive%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20technical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnarrow%20or%20very%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbroad%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwide%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmall%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwiden%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstrait%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blines%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bline%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbroaden%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthin%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20or%20narrow%3B%2Cc0) shows that *narrow* has two opposites, *wide* and *broad*.