# Kinder vs More Kind

Tags: comparisons

Do we say "kinder" or "more kind"? I found people saying both things over the internet and got confused. Which is the correct one?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Actually, the canonical question might be [More clear vs. clearer: when to use "more" instead of "-er"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2166/2303).

Comment: so kinder is the way to go?

Comment: Context would be helpful....do you have an example sentence?

Comment: Adjectives with one syllable use -er/-est. So the comparison forms are kind, kinder, kindest.

Answer (score 1):

Kinder.  More kind is not the correct way to say it.  Never trust what you read in blogs.  I have found a lot of very educated people who cannot write English properly.