# more fair or fairer - Is "more fair" an acceptable alternative to "fairer"

Tags: word-choice

Is it acceptable to say "more fair" as opposed to "fairer" ? Is one more appropriate than the other?

Comment: Please let us know what you have learned from your research into this question prior to asking the question here. Adding that information to your question will help answerers avoid duplicating your efforts and will, if nothing else, demonstrate that you have consulted some standard resources to no avail.

Comment: My love is more fair than a summer's day.

Comment: There is, in general, no rule against using a "more xxxx" form, even though the "xxxxer" form is available as an "approved" word.  Using the "more" form is often done for poetic reasons, or simply for a change in emphasis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one-syllable and two-syllable adjectives have their comparative formed by adding -er. 
Three-syllable adjective and longer ones use more + adj.
"Fairer" is the correct choice to make.

Comment: Cool - your answer led me to find this other related thread: [“More clear” vs “Clearer”: when to use “more” instead of “-er”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er)

Comment: As the comments in the "More clear" vs "Clearer" Q&A suggest, the normal treatment of a particular two-syllable word is by no means predictable solely on the basis that the root word has two syllables. For example: _heavier_, _loftier_, and _speedier_, but _more polite_, _more spacious_, and _more sordid_.

Comment: For that matter, at the one-syllable level,  _more burnt_, _more stunned_, _more wrecked_; and at the three-syllable level, _unhappier_, which is [well established as an alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+unhappy%2Cunhappier&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20unhappy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunhappier%3B%2Cc0) to _more unhappy_ in some settings.

Comment: Funner........?